# Get value of Label in Javascript as Datetime

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to take label value and convert into datetime in javascript. I have a label in that I have binded datetime from database.

**Asp.net Code**

```
<asp:Label ID="expiryTimeLbl" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
//10/27/2020 8:10:00 AM
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById("expiryTimeLbl")).getTime();
```

Now I will compare **countDownDate** with **CurrentTime**. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById('<%=expiryTimeLbl.ClientID %>')).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textContent` or `innerHTML`. Try below

```
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById("expiryTimeLbl").textContent).getTime();
```

or if any master page involve.

```
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById('<%=expiryTimeLbl.ClientID %>').textContent).getTime();
```

for specific Hour/minute/seconds

```
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById("expiryTimeLbl").textContent).getHours();
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById("expiryTimeLbl").textContent).getMinutes();
var countDownDate = new Date(document.getElementById("expiryTimeLbl").textContent).getSeconds();
```